# Need help formulating a Vim Search & Replace

Tags: vim, search, find-and-replace

I have a large html file in which I need to search and replace over 2000 occurrences of specific string.  I could do it manually but I'm sure there is a power Vim search and replace command that could do it.

I have footnotes that I need to replace a specific portion of the hyperlink text.

The footnote link is formatted liked this:

```
<sup><a href='#footnote-2020'>2020</a></sup>
```

There are over 2000 footnotes each labelled 1-2020.  I would like to remove the anchor text (2020 in the example above) and replace it with a *.  I would like to leave the href text '#footnote-2020' as it is in order to preserve the link.

Are there any power Vim users who could come up with a quick search and replace command?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't help you with Vim, but would like an Emacs solution :-P. Or maybe sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s,\(<a href='#footnote-\d\+'>\)\d\+\(</a>\),\1*\2,g
```

To break it down:

`%` - Operate over the whole file (this is a special range)
`,...,...,` - Normally the delimiter for :substitute is /, but it can be anything. I used commas because of the </a> tag.
`\(...\)` - Create a sub-expression, for use in the replacement pattern. Two of these are used.
`\d\+` - Match any digit, and the `\+` makes it match one or more.
`\1` / `\2` - In the replace pattern, gets substituted with the first and second sub-expression mentioned earlier.
`g` - The "g" flag after a replacement pattern says to operate globally in each line, and not just on the first match in a line.

All this and more is explained in `:help pattern.txt` but that might be overwhelming.  There is a book called "Mastering Regular Expressions" that can be helpful.